# String SHA1 in Julia

Tags: julia

I have an ordered set of points (x,y pairs) I would like to use as a key in a dictionary.

My original approach in ruby was to get a string representation of the points and then SHA1 the results.

What would be the best way to accomplish this in Julia?

Edit:

The key that I want to create is the set of points, not the individual points within the set.

I have a process that creates a set of unique integer points and I want to see if I have encountered this particular set of points before.  I also want to store some information about this particular set of points.  For example how many times have I seen this configuration.

The length of the set of points varies between 20 and 180ish.

With a SHA1 hash of the string representation of these points I know that my key is going to be 40 characters long regardless of the length of the points.

In effect I'm using SHA1 to compress my key to keep the size of my dictionary as small as I can.  I would like this dictionary to grow to a fairly large size.

Comment: Why not directly use the x,y pairs as keys?

Comment: I edited the original comment to make it a bit clearer.  I am looking to use a set of unique ordered pairs as a key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the points them directly as keys of a dictionary, e.g.

```
points = [(rand(),rand()) for i in 1:100]
a_dict = [p => rand(1:10000) for p in points]
@show points[1]
@show a_dict[points[1]]
```

produces

```
points[1] => (0.4374267407775083,0.32232663537074036)
a_dict[points[1]] => 4102
```

EDIT: The question is asking about *lists* of points rather than single pairs. Its hard to tell from your question, but if you wanted to throw out the lists of points, then I'd just use the `hash` function, which is what a dictionary uses:

```
julia> x = [(rand(),rand()) for i in 1:100];

julia> y = copy(x);

julia> z = [(rand(),rand()) for i in 1:100];

julia> hash(x)
0x2dd258e3af0ec93a

julia> hash(y)
0x2dd258e3af0ec93a

julia> hash(z)
0x6449b750e42e6bc6

julia> some_dict = [hash(x) => 1, hash(z) => 1]
Dict{Uint64,Int64} with 2 entries:
  0x6449b750e42e6bc6 => 1
  0x2dd258e3af0ec93a => 1

julia> if hash(y) in keys(some_dict)
         some_dict[hash(y)] += 1
       else
         some_dict[hash(y)] = 1
       end

julia> some_dict
Dict{Uint64,Int64} with 2 entries:
  0x6449b750e42e6bc6 => 1
  0x2dd258e3af0ec93a => 2
```

If you actually need to retrieve what the sets of points are though, which seems likely, then you can just use a dictionary directly with the set of points as the key, i.e.

```
julia> other_dict = [x=>1,z=>1]
Dict{Array{(Float64,Float64),1},Int64} with 2 entries:
  [(0.6453074757765922,0.0958215… => 1
  [(0.5283378708792779,0.8418390… => 1

julia> other_dict[y] += 1
2

julia> other_dict
Dict{Array{(Float64,Float64),1},Int64} with 2 entries:
  [(0.6453074757765922,0.0958215… => 1
  [(0.5283378708792779,0.8418390… => 2
```

This (using mutable keys) is perfectly fine in Julia (although bad things will happen if you change the keys of dictionary once they've been added, of course).

Comment: I edited the original comment to be more clear.  I would like to use a set of ordered pairs as the key, not the ordered pairs themselves.

Comment: Thank you.  The hash function is exactly what I was looking for.